# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline without Jenkins file in the repository

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am trying to upgrade my current regression infrastructure to use [pipeline plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin) and I realize there are two methods: `scripted pipeline` and `declarative pipeline`. Going through multiple articles, I realize that `declarative pipeline` is more future proof and more powerful, hence I am inclined to use this. But there seems to be following restrictions which I don't want to have in my setup:

1. The `jenkinsfile` needs to be in the repository. I don't want to keep my `jenkinsfile` in the code repository.
2. Since the `jenkinsfile` needs to be in SCM. Does it mean I cannot test any modification in the file until I check that in to the repository.

Any details on the above will be very helpful.

Comment: are you concerned about pipeline testing the most?

Comment: @Muatik that's one of the concerns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declarative pipelines are compiled to scripted ones, so those will definitely not go away. But declarative ones are a bit easier to handle, so all fine for you.

You don't have to check a `Jenkinsfile` into VCS. You can also set up a job of type *Pipeline* and define it there. But this has the usual disadvantages like no history etc.

When using multi-branch pipelines, i.e., every branch containing a `Jenkinsfile` generating an own job, you just push your changed pipeline to a new branch and execute it. Once it's done, you merge it.

This approach certainly increases feedback cycles a bit, but it just applies the same principles as when writing your software. For experimentation, just set up a *Pipeline* type job and play around. Afterwards, commit it to a branch, test it, review it, merge it.

Comment: I have tried using Pipeline job but there I can only write `scripted pipeline` and can't use `declarative pipeline`. I have checked my Jenkins version (>2.7), checked my pipeline plugin version (>1.5). But it only accepts `scripted pipeline` there. Any extra settings needed for the same?

Comment: What code did you try? I'm pretty sure it accepts also declarative pipelines (as said, they are just compiled to scripted ones).

Comment: Looks like it needed restart. Thanks. Got the `declarative pipeline` working.

Comment: @RachitAgrawal What was the issue ? I have the same problem

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Pipeline Multibranch Defaults Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-multibranch-defaults-plugin) for that. It allows you to define the Jenkinsfile in the web UI (with the Config File Provider plugin) itself and then reference that file from a Multibranch Pipeline.

Comment: This is interesting. Is it possible to define more than one "default" Jenkinsfile in order to set different default pipelines for different Jenkins multibranch projects?